# My relational schema and a few questions about relations and duplicate values in columns

Tags: database-design, erd, duplication, relations

I'm trying to create database in which I could store thousands of job postings. I put here 5 sample records of these job postings so that you could better understand how everything looks like:
[image]

Now, based on above data I've created relational database schema filled with this data:

[image]
Because I'm not experienced in creating such schemas, I'd like to ask a few questions:

1. Some of the columns, or to be more precise cells contain duplicate values. For example in `Job Posting` table there is column `title` and as you can see some titles duplicate (2x "Python developer" and 2x "QA Engineer"). Is this a problem if there is thousands of same job posting titles? Shouldn't I delete `title` column from `Job posting` table, create it as a separate table so that there wouldn't be repetitions and then establish relation with `Job posting`? Same things applies also to `currency`, `type_of_employment` and `per` columns in `Salary` table.
2. If you take a look at `Level` table (on the right in my relational schema) you will see that it contains levels which range from "trainee" to "expert", each with its own ID. The same range applies to `level` column in `Skills employer looks for` table. Because names for levels in this column are same as in `Level` table maybe it's better to establish relation between these two tables (`Level` and `Skills employer looks for`) and instead of putting names of levels I would use foreign keys referencing to `Level` table.
3. I've moved info about salary to separate table (`Salary` table). Should it be done in this way? Wouldn't it be better to just delete `Salary` table and move all of its columns to `Job posting` table?
4. Each job posting contains information about skills employer looks for (`Skills` column in Sample job posting records). Because each job posting may contain information about one or more skills employer is looking for and each skill can be associated with one or more job postings it's natural to establish many-to-many relationship between `Job posting` and `Skills` tables with linking table between them (it's `Skills employer looks for` table). But honestly, what is the point of showing this relationship in this way? I mean I could just delete `Skills` table and in place where `FK_skills_ID` column is now I could create `skills` column with name of particular skill in each cell.
5. If you have any suggestions how to improve my schema feel free to tell me. I would be glad to receive any feedback.